# Get number of elements in an Enum type and iterate over them

Tags: c#, reflection, enums

Is there a way to iterate over elements in an enum type? Something like:

```
public enum MyEnum
{
   One,
   Two,
   Three,
}

foreach(var temp in MyEnum)
{
    //Do something
}
```

My be its possible by refelection or something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Enum.GetValues(typeof(MyEnum))`:

```
foreach(MyEnum temp in Enum.GetValues(typeof(MyEnum))) 
{ 
    //Do something 
}
```

Please note: I use `MyEnum temp` instead of `var temp`, because `GetValues` doesn't return a strong typed array.

Answer (score 3):

Use [System.Array Enum.GetValues(Type)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.getvalues.aspx) method.

```
 foreach(var temp in Enum.GetValues(typeof(MyEnum)))
  {
      //code
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach (var name in Enum.GetNames(typeof(MyEnum))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var test = Enum.GetValues(typeof(MyEnum));
foreach (MyEnum e in test)
{
    Console.Write(e);
}
```

See [Enum.GetValues](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.getvalues%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)